# jQuery submit form normally or Ajax dependant on variable using FontAwesome buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using buttons for submit, as that is the only easy way to use fontawesome buttons. I detect which button was selected and place that value in a hidden field so that it is available in my Ajax routine.

This presents a problem, as one button requires a normal submit, as it goes to a script that creates a pdf.

The other conditions submit using Ajax. I attempted the following which, of course, will not work, as it creates a recursion loop.
Cannot figure a means to do this without creating a submit loop.

In Form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Clicked" name="Clicked" value="" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Create" style="display:inline;"> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> <span>Create Bill</span></i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Reset" style="display:inline;"> <i class="fa fa-times"> <span>Reset</span></i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="SaveData"> <i class="fa fa-archive"> <span>Save Only</span></i></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Create-Save"> <i class="fa fa-archive"> <span>Create and Save</span></i></button>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.ClickCheck').click(function()
    {
        var ButtonID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#Clicked').val(ButtonID);
    });

    $("#MyForm").on("submit", function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var Form = $('#MyForm');
        var Valid = verify();
        if(Valid)
        {
            if($('#Clicked').val() == "Create")
            {
                $(Form).attr('action', './blformpdf.php');
                $(Form).submit();
            }
            else
            {
               $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "scripts/Ajax.php",
                   data: Form.serialize(),
                   success: function(response)
                   {
                       console.log(response);
                   }
               });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was simply to use links rather than <input> or <button>.
Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Clicked" name="Clicked" value="" />
<a class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Create" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> <span>Create Bill</span></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Reset" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="fa fa-times"> <span>Reset</span></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="SaveData" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="fa fa-archive"> <span>Save Only</span></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="btn btn-success ClickCheck" id="Create-Save" href="javascript:void(0)"> <i class="fa fa-archive"> <span>Create and Save</span></i></a>
```

One of these buttons is a reset. Although you can define a <button> as type="reset", for consistency, as well as other reasons, I left that too as a link and, since the button id is part of my post, the Ajax script detects that and just returns a null, then used a jQuery reset to clear the form after the null Ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.ClickCheck').click(function()
    {
        var ButtonID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#Clicked').val(ButtonID);
        var Form = $('#MyForm');
        var Valid = verify(); // form verify function
        if(Valid)
        {
            if(ButtonID == "Create") // Send to PDF script
            {
                $(Form).attr('action', './blformpdf.php');
                $(Form).submit();
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/Ajax.php",
                    data: Form.serialize(),
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        // Do whatever here with response data
                    }  
                }
                if(ButtonID == "Reset")
                {
                    $('#MyForm').trigger("reset");
                    $('#Clicked').val('');
                }
            }
        }    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback should be done from `verify()` , I've written an example .

```js
var goIsWaiting=false;
var goIsActive=false;

function go(){
  if(goIsActive)
    adviseGoIsActive()
  else{
    console.log("Go Is Waiting !");
    goIsWaiting=true;
  }
}

function activate(){
  //.. Doing some stuff here
  if(goIsWaiting) adviseGoIsActive();
  goIsActive=true;
}

function adviseGoIsActive(){
  console.log("Go Is Active !")
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Go" onClick="go()">
<input type="submit" value="Activate Go Action" onClick="activate()">
```

Comment: @Ashref Sorry, I was trying to keep it simple, but that doesn't really explain the problem, which is that I am using buttons rather than input, in order to use fontawesome buttons, which is consistent with the rest of the site. I've rewritten my question. The problem, I believe, with buttons is that they will submit the form regardless.

Comment: @RationalRabbit I'm sorry , But I'm still confused about what really you are looking for . You may use `Button` instead of `Input` in my solution though .

Comment: @Ashref Thanks much for your help Ashraf. Can't style inputs, and the problem with using  <button>, is whether defined as  "submit" or not, if it is part of a form, it assumes submit. Although you can define it as type="reset", and it will reset the form instead. You can set an onclick in the button, but it's still going to submit the form as well and if you don't have a method defined at the top of your form, it will default to GET. The solution was in front of my nose. I just replaced the buttons with links that formatted fine with FontAwesome. I'll post the code below.